# How to replace default bluetooth manager of Ubuntu 19.10 with blueman?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I installed blueman on Ubuntu 19.10 and see two icons of Bluetooth: one from blueman and one default, so is it possible to replace the system icon with blueman's one?

Comment: Maybe not replace but disabling it? What did you try so far?

Comment: Disabling of default is an option too. Can you help me disable it? I try because now I have two Bluetooth icons in my top bar and it is confusing